# Grails: Bi-directional one-to-many results in endless recursion (StackOverflow)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, stack-overflow, one-to-many

I've recently taken over a Grails project from another person.

I'm using Grails 3.2.11 and Hibernate 4.3.10

I'm adding new features and one of them is expanding the datamodel. There are Stories with Tags and I want to combine them into TagAliasGroups. So I've added:

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

@EqualsAndHashCode
class TagAliasGroup {
    Date created = new Date()

    Set aliases

    static hasMany = [aliases: Tag]
[...]
```

In the Tag class I referred to that:

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

@EqualsAndHashCode
class Tag {
    String tag
    Boolean promoted
    Boolean isCategory
    Date created = new Date()

    TagAliasGroup aliasGroup

[...]
```

The DB-Schema was updated correctly and I can write new data sets just fine. But when trying to access the "aliases" set from the TagAliasGroup, I get an endless recursion inside of Hibernate and a StackOverflow Exception as a consequence:

```
def getAliasList() {
    try
    {
        if(aliasGroup)
        {
            Set al = aliasGroup.aliases
            // al.remove(this)

            return al.join(", ")
        }
        else return ""
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return e.getMessage()
    }
}
```

The "return al.join(", ")" throws the exception, but any other access to the Collection has the same result. The debugger also gets an exception when trying to evaluate "al".
When stepping into Hibernate at that point, it looks to me as the code tries to dereference and resolve the proxy for the TagAliasGroup over and over again.

I made a simple workaround by making "aliases" transient:

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

@EqualsAndHashCode
class TagAliasGroup {
    Date created = new Date()

    // Set aliases
    // static hasMany = [aliases: Tag]

    def getAliases() {
        return Tag.findAllByAliasGroup(this)
    }
```

This is working perfectly, but it cannot be the correct solution. Especially since I'd expect that hibernate would cache the result and be more efficient because of that.

What am I missing? It must be something obvious but I cannot figure out what.

Here's the exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.isDebugEnabled(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:67)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:429)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:257)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:201)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1933)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:447)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.HashCodeHelper.updateHash(HashCodeHelper.java:84)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.HashCodeHelper.updateHash(HashCodeHelper.java:84)
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:344)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:251)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:238)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:211)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:255)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:218)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1933)
```

Repeating from here on endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll prefix this answer by saying in my experience using hasMany, belongsTo, or any of the other qualifiers causes way more problems than it helps.  Unless you absolutely need what they provide (cascading, specific hibernate level caching, etc). Just stick with keeping the simple reference you have on Tag and remove the 'hasMany' from TagAliasGroup, and use dynamic finder to load the tags as per your workaround.  That said, sticking with your design, I think you need 'belongsTo' to avoid the recursion of a circular back reference to TagAliasGroup for the given tag.

```
class Tag {
 ....
 static belongsTo = [TagAliasGroup: aliasGroup]
 ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had already tried to establish a belongsTo annotation in both directions, but I just tried it again, just to be save.

The result is the same endless recursion, I'm afraid :(